# htaccess modifications caused ACCESS FORBIDDEN, ERROR 403 cannot correct even deleting htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Playing around with 'friendly URLs' and created an htaccess file with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^modules/posts/questions_all.php/?$  modules/posts/questions_all.php    [NC,L]
```

Intent was to be able to redirect 
http://localhost/modules/posts/questions_all.php/1234 (with friendly URL suffix /1234) to the normal page
http://localhost/modules/posts/questions_all.php

Then I tried adding other lines as suggested in another web post (but NOT understanding what they really do), making it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule    ^modules/posts/questions_all.php/?$    modules/posts/questions_all.php    [NC,L]
```

After this, it seems like I started getting the 'ACCESS FORBIDDEN, ERROR 403' message when I tried to access the normal page through the HREF link.  The HREF link is unchanged, but now the URL in the address bar reads:

```
http://localhost/C:/xampp/htdocs/Data/anyCompany/modules/posts/questions_all.php
```

rather than:

```
http://localhost/modules/posts/questions_all.php
```

Now I cannot seem to get the system back to functioning with this link anymore.  Even deleting the htaccess file did not correct it.  Did the RewriteCond commands change some settings elsewhere that I need to somehow undo?

Comment: You should probably start "destination" url with `/`: `/modules/posts/....`

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how it got into the above error state, but clearing the cache fixed this problem.  Didn't think the .htaccess file would get cached...